# SQLServerException: The connection is closed and not auto reconnecting to secondary db after failover

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, hikaricp, mssql-jdbc

I have a springboot app where it is connecting to Azure SQL Database. And I wanted to setup auto-failover of Azure SQL Server.

I have **primary sql server1** (*server1.database.windows.net*) in region A with a single db("demo").
Then, I set up auto failover group for server 1 by creating a **secondary server 2** (*server2.database.windows.net*) in region B for the same db.

Currently using the below JDBC connection string for configuration:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<my-failover-group-name>:1433;database=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;applicationIntent=ReadWrite;
```

**Hikari CP** is having connections able to connect with the above connection string to my primary DB but when I did a manual failover on azure portal, database connections should automatically reconnect to the secondary server which has become primary now but I keep on getting the below exception:-

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

- mssql-jdbc version:- 8.2.2.jre8
- Springboot version:- 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: I've read your previous post. I also have springboot app and a failover group ,  I created a same username and password between two db servers. When I did a manual failover on azure portal, my springboot app will connect to the db server automatically. So I suggest to to use a same username and password to solve the problem.

Comment: Connecting to a failover group is like connecting to one db server and leave other things to it.

Comment: @JosephXu, I have the same username and password for both the servers. Just the server name for primary and secondary is different. The final username would be user@server1 and user@server2 respectively. I am able to connect with mentioned failover group using DB client when failover happens. Its just that once I am doing a failover, connections to the DB are giving me SQLErrorException saying the connection is closed. And these connections are not repaired to connect to the latest server.

Comment: Please change 'user@server1' and 'user@server2' to just 'user'. It works well.

Comment: @Joseph Xu, Just tried with single user 'demo' for both the server, it is not letting me connect and giving the same exception when the failover happens. Any other way you suggest. Can it be a Hikari CP error or any configuration error ?

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties file:
At `username` property, you can remove the `@server1` or `@server2`. So that when we do manual failover, our spring-boot app will connect to the failover group automatically with no errors.
[image]

I tried several times and all succeeded.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<FailoverGroupname>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<DatabaseName>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=joseph
spring.datasource.password=***

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

---

**update:**
My application.property is as follow:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<FailoverGroupName>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<DatabaseName>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=joseph
spring.datasource.password=<password>

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

# Hikari will use the above plus the following to setup connection pooling
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=15
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=DatebookHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

When I start my app, it shows:
[image]

When I do failover manually, it shows:
[image]

Comment: Xu, I tried creating a user demo for both the servers with the failover group name in connection string and the result is same. Still it is not letting me connect through application when failover happens.

Comment: This maybe a Hikaricp configuration error. I'm using [Spring Data jdbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jdbc-with-azure-sql-server?toc=/azure/azure-sql/toc.json&bc=/azure/bread/toc.json) to connect to the failover group.

Comment: Xu, Thanks for helping out but it seems a different issue. I"ll update the answer when I found out the issue.

Comment: Hi, I mean that you may try to use Spring Data to connect to the failover group according to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jdbc-with-azure-sql-server?toc=/azure/azure-sql/toc.json&bc=/azure/bread/toc.json). The **Hikari CP** is the default database connection pool in Spring Boot. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Xu, The app is using Hikari by default. Whenever the failover happens, it gives Broken pipe write failed and then does not refresh the connections and that gives Connection is closed. Can you share the hikari configuration

Comment: Yes, please see my update part of my answer. Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: When during doing failover manually, it will be read-only, that's right?

Comment: Are you using mssql-jdbc because I tried with same Hikari 3.4.5 version and same configuration and the exception comes like "connection is closed" and it fails till infinity. Connections could not recover even after the grace period

Comment: Have you add your client IP to the server2's firewall rule?

Comment: Yeah have added that before itself. Looks like some dependency is overwriting the hikaricp